# Show that f attains its (unique) minimum at the centroid of a set of points

Tags: analysis

> **Problem Statement:** Let $z_1 , \dots, z_m$ be m points in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Define $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ via 
>   $$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^m ||x-z_i||^2$$
>   Show that f attains its unique minimum at $x = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m z_i$ (the centroid of these  points)

I know that I have to find what $Df$ is and show that it has a critical point, and that that critical point is the centroid of the set of points z. But I'm not sure how to do this. I can write
$$f(x) = ||x-z_1||^2 + ||x-z_2||^2 + \cdots ||x-z_m||^2$$
but this doesn't help me much because I'm not sure what norm I am using so finding the derivative of this would probably be difficult.

Comment: You probably should figure out what the norm is, then! If it's true, then it's probably the Euclidean norm.

Comment: I decided to work with the assumption that it is the Euclidean norm and I'm making progress. The problem doesn't explicitly say that's what I should use, so I guess that's where my confusion is from.